# Newenvironment strange behavior

Tags: environments

I'm trying to understand why :

this works :

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{myenv}
{\begin{tabular}{@{}l}}
{\end{tabular}}

\newenvironment{myotherenv}
{}
{}


\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
    Thing\\
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

This work too :

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{myenv}
{\begin{tabular}{@{}l}}
{\end{tabular}}

\newenvironment{myotherenv}
{}
{}


\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
    \begin{myotherenv}
        Thing
    \end{myotherenv}
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

But this throws errors :

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{myenv}
{\begin{tabular}{@{}l}}
{\end{tabular}}

\newenvironment{myotherenv}
{}
{}


\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
    \begin{myotherenv}
        Thing\\
    \end{myotherenv}
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is nothing to do with the definitions, you would get the same error if you directly used the construct. You can not start an environment in one cell and end it in another,

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
\begin{empty}
\\
\end{empty}
\end{tabular}
```

would give the same error as `\\`  ends the table cell so ends the group generating an error as the environment is not finished.

Comment: I see, i will have to use pair of macro instead of environnement then